# How can I make an input label clickable? (initiate text input)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a project fiddling with animations on select and was creating a signup form (re-created it on my replit - https://replit.com/join/gzflphmalc-jeezgeorge
)

Everything seems to be working fine except for the fact that when I click on the name of the label (name, email, password) it doesn't initiate the text input.

How can I wrap the label with the input so that when I click on the name as well it will initiate the input.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Do you mean when a user clicks on the "Log in to your account" label, then the cursor goes to the input box?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Replit account so I can't see your project. But if I understand your question, you can use `id` and `for` HTML attributes for that:

```html
<label for="name">First Name</label>
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="e.g. John Doe" />
```

Once you click on the label `First Name`, it will focus on the text input.